# Query MongoDB to fetch a nested array with skip/limit by nested object key range in Django using pymongo

Tags: django, mongodb, pymongo

I am learning Django with pymongo.

I have a MongoDB collection where I am storing some words and their year-wise occurrences in some books.

The documents are stored in MongoDB in the following format:

```json
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"625c51eec27c99b793074501"
   },
   "word":"entropy",
   "occurrence":13,
   "year":{
      "1942":[
         {
            "book":{
               "$oid":"625c51eec27c99b7930744f9"
            },
            "number":8,
            "sentence":[
               1,
               288,
               322,
               1237,
               2570,
               2585,
               2617,
               2634
            ]
         }
      ],
      "1947":[
         {
            "book":{
               "$oid":"625c5280c27c99b793077042"
            },
            "number":5,
            "sentence":[
               377,
               2108,
               2771,
               3467,
               3502
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Now I want to get the list of the sentences with *skip* and *limit* (and the respective book id) queried by *_id* and for specific *year* range.

For example,

1. I want to fetch an array where each row will be a dictionary containing 'year', 'book' and 'sentence'.
2. The array will be queried by the *_id* and *year* range.
3. A *skip* and *limit* will be applied on the *sentence* list

Is this a possible task using Django and pymongo? If yes, what is the fastest method?

So far I have done this:

```py
search= {'$and': [{"_id": word_id_obj, "year.1942": {"$exists": 1}}]}
datalist= []
word_docs= wordcollec.find(search, {'year': 1, '_id': 0}).skip(1).limit(5)
sentlist['recordsFiltered']+= wordcollec.count_documents(search)

for b in word_docs:
    year_data= b['year'][1942]
    for by in year_data:
        i= i+1
        this_word= {'serial': i, 'year': cyear, 'book': str(by['book'])}
        datalist.append(this_word)
```

But obviously, it is not giving the desired result as the *skip* and *limit* are being applied to the root document object. Also the the *year* has a fixed value and no range.

It seems using '$slice' is an option. But I cannot figure it out.

Thanks for reading this far. And a lot more if you can throw some light.

Comment: Using data as a key, like "1942" and "1947", is usually not a good design, as you've discovered with your desired queries.  Is it possible to change the design?  If not, the queries are still possible but they won't be succinct, nor efficient.

Comment: Thank you. Yes... changing the DB design is my last resort. I was checking if it works with the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to:

> ... fetch an array where each row will be a dictionary
> containing 'year', 'book' and 'sentence'.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$set": { "designWorkAround": { "$objectToArray": "$year" } } },
  { "$set": {
      "designWorkAround": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$designWorkAround",
          "as": "yearArray",
          "in": {
            "year": "$$yearArray.k",
            "books": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$$yearArray.v",
                "as": "bookArray",
                "in": {
                  "bookId": "$$bookArray.book",
                  "number": "$$bookArray.number",
                  "sentence": "$$bookArray.sentence"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { "$unwind": "$designWorkAround" },
  { "$unwind": "$designWorkAround.books" },
  { "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "year": "$designWorkAround.year",
      "book": "$designWorkAround.books.bookId",
      "sentence": "$designWorkAround.books.sentence"
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QrA40skt7u3).

I don't know all the data generation nor queries that you might want, but I would probably redesign the collection and have something like one document per book with all the relevant fields in the document.  This would make querying, indexing, etc., simpler and more efficient.

Comment: So many thanks for your effort. I have actually redesigned the collection, but facing new problems. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71962069/django-pymongo-search-sort-limit-on-inner-array-and-count-them